# How to search and swap numbers in array?

Tags: java, arrays, jgrasp

I'm currently creating a 24 puzzle. If I input "move" followed by "12" Then the array index that corresponds with the number will search if zero is adjacent to itself. If 0 is found, it will swap places, otherwise it would say "wrong number"

This is what I have so far, but the numbers won't budge.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Board
{
   File file = new File("input.txt"); 
   File out = new File("output.txt");
   int[][] the_frame = new int[5][5];
   Scanner command = new Scanner(System.in);



   public void readInitialBoard() throws Exception
   {

      PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
      Scanner input = new Scanner(file); //Reads the input from file "input.txt"
      for ( int row = 0; row < the_frame.length; row++) //5 rows in total
      {
         for (int column = 0; column < the_frame[row].length; column++) //5 columns read from each row
         {
            the_frame[row][column] = input.nextInt(); //each values are put into array
         }
      }

   } 

   public int makeMove(String move, int num) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
   {
      Scanner command = new Scanner(System.in);
      move = command.nextLine();
      if (move.equals("move")) //"move" is inputted follow by number. If number not next to 0, then it will be considered an incorrect move.
      {
         num = command.nextInt(); //input number
         for ( int row = 0; row < the_frame.length; row++ )
         {
            for (int column = 0; column < the_frame[row].length; column++)
            {


               if (num == the_frame[row][column]) //"searches" the number within the array. If found it goes to next step
               {

                  if (num >= 100 * (the_frame[row+1][column]))
                  {
                     the_frame[row+1][column] = num;
                     the_frame[row][column] = 0;
                     System.out.println("Success");
                  }
                  else if (num >= 100 * (the_frame[row][column+1]))
                  {
                     the_frame[row][column+1] = num;
                     the_frame[row][column] = 0;
                     System.out.println("Success");
                  }
                  else if (num >= 100 * (the_frame[row-1][column]))
                  {
                     the_frame[row-1][column] = num;
                     the_frame[row][column] = 0;
                     System.out.println("Success");
                  }
                  else if (num >= 100 * (the_frame[row][column-1]))
                  {
                     the_frame[row][column-1] = num;
                     the_frame[row][column] = 0;
                     System.out.println("Success");
                  }

                  else
                  {
                     System.out.println("Wrong move");
                  }
                  System.out.println("please continue");
               }


            }
         }
      } 
      else if (move.equals("help"))
      {
         System.out.println("help");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("Invalid number found");
      }
      return num;
   }

   public void showBoard()
   {
      String leftAlignFormat = "| %-2s |";
      System.out.println("Current board");
      for (int row = 0; row < the_frame.length; row++)
      {
         System.out.println("------------------------------");
         for (int column = 0; column < the_frame[row].length; column++) 
         {
            System.out.format(leftAlignFormat, the_frame[row][column]);
         }
         System.out.println();
      } 
   }

   public boolean isCorrect()
   {
      return false;
   }


}
```

This is the result of trying to "move" the number 12

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java Driver

Current board
------------------------------
| 1  || 2  || 3  || 4  || 5  |
------------------------------
| 6  || 7  || 8  || 9  || 10 |
------------------------------
| 11 || 12 || 0  || 13 || 14 |
------------------------------
| 15 || 16 || 17 || 18 || 19 |
------------------------------
| 20 || 21 || 22 || 23 || 24 |
move
12
Success
please continue
Wrong move
please continue
Current board
------------------------------
| 1  || 2  || 3  || 4  || 5  |
------------------------------
| 6  || 7  || 8  || 9  || 10 |
------------------------------
| 11 || 0  || 12 || 13 || 14 |
------------------------------
| 15 || 16 || 17 || 18 || 19 |
------------------------------
| 20 || 21 || 22 || 23 || 24 |


 ----jGRASP exec: java Driver

Current board
------------------------------
| 1  || 2  || 3  || 4  || 5  |
------------------------------
| 6  || 7  || 8  || 9  || 10 |
------------------------------
| 11 || 12 || 0  || 13 || 14 |
------------------------------
| 15 || 16 || 17 || 18 || 19 |
------------------------------
| 20 || 21 || 22 || 23 || 24 |
move
17
Success
please continue
Current board
------------------------------
| 1  || 2  || 3  || 4  || 5  |
------------------------------
| 6  || 7  || 8  || 9  || 10 |
------------------------------
| 11 || 12 || 17 || 13 || 14 |
------------------------------
| 15 || 16 || 0  || 18 || 19 |
------------------------------
| 20 || 21 || 22 || 23 || 24 |
move
18
Success
please continue
Current board
------------------------------
| 1  || 2  || 3  || 4  || 5  |
------------------------------
| 6  || 7  || 8  || 9  || 10 |
------------------------------
| 11 || 12 || 17 || 13 || 14 |
------------------------------
| 15 || 16 || 18 || 0  || 19 |
------------------------------
| 20 || 21 || 22 || 23 || 24 |
move
13
Success
please continue
Success
please continue
Current board
------------------------------
| 1  || 2  || 3  || 4  || 5  |
------------------------------
| 6  || 7  || 8  || 9  || 10 |
------------------------------
| 11 || 12 || 17 || 13 || 14 |
------------------------------
| 15 || 16 || 18 || 0  || 19 |
------------------------------
| 20 || 21 || 22 || 23 || 24 |
move
23
Current board
------------------------------
| 1  || 2  || 3  || 4  || 5  |
------------------------------
| 6  || 7  || 8  || 9  || 10 |
------------------------------
| 11 || 12 || 17 || 13 || 14 |
------------------------------
| 15 || 16 || 18 || 0  || 19 |
------------------------------
| 20 || 21 || 22 || 23 || 24 |
move
19
Current board
------------------------------
| 1  || 2  || 3  || 4  || 5  |
------------------------------
| 6  || 7  || 8  || 9  || 10 |
------------------------------
| 11 || 12 || 17 || 13 || 14 |
------------------------------
| 15 || 16 || 18 || 0  || 19 |
------------------------------
| 20 || 21 || 22 || 23 || 24 |
move
18
Success
please continue
Success
please continue
Current board
------------------------------
| 1  || 2  || 3  || 4  || 5  |
------------------------------
| 6  || 7  || 8  || 9  || 10 |
------------------------------
| 11 || 12 || 17 || 13 || 14 |
------------------------------
| 15 || 16 || 18 || 0  || 19 |
------------------------------
| 20 || 21 || 22 || 23 || 24 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `makeMove` method keeps scanning even after it finds the number.  So it finds 12, moves it right and then immediately finds it again and tries to move it again.

Add `return num;` right after `System.out.println("please continue");` and see if that fixes your problem.

**Edit**:

You also have a problem with not checking for boundaries.  Try this:

```
if (row < 4 && num >= 100 * (the_frame[row + 1][column])) {
    ...
} else if (column < 4 && num >= 100 * (the_frame[row][column + 1])) {
    ...
} else if (row > 0 && num >= 100 * (the_frame[row - 1][column])) {
    ...
} else if (column > 0 && num >= 100 * (the_frame[row][column - 1])) {
    ...
```

Comment: It works, but if the number is trying to move to the right on the way top, the number won't budge. Same thing when i try to move the number to the last column of arrays and move the numbers to the last row of arrays.